# How to split a column with percentages and words

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-cleaning

I need to clean a column of data which contains the percentage coverage of different materials. I would like to split the columns into e.g. '30% water | 20% grass | 20% coarse', so that each percentage of a material is in a different column.

Is there a formula for achieving this? Possibly by adding spaces between the % and following words first?

[image: Subset of the columns I wish to split into E.g. 30% water | 20% grass | 20% coarse dirt]

Comment: What is your excel version? What would be exact output for first cell of your given data?

Comment: My excel version is 16.63.1. This data is just a subset/example of what I am trying to achieve, my exact desired outcome for this is: first row: 50% wood chips | 20% grass | 23% coarse dirt. Second row: 30% grass | 7% gravel. Third row: 16% coarse dirt | 45% water. Fourth row: 21% water

Comment: Version means, Excel 365 or Excel 2016?

Comment: Sorry, my version is Excel 365 then

Answer (score 0):

I managed it without difficult formula.

Just type some examples like i did in column C (2 or 3 examples) then mark all the cells and choose Flash Fill.

Do for each column.

Last column you can clean with this formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("%";E3));E3;"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately this solution does not work for the full dataset. Some columns end up with two things conjoined within them (e.g. 16%coarse dirt45% water) and consequently the subsequent cells on the row are incorrect. Is there a formula I could use to avoid this issue?

Comment: This method also often leaves out words of each part, e.g. rather than 'coarse dirt' the new column will only say 'coarse'.

Comment: @KatieJones maybe you need to enter few more examples, I would make sure to have the one with most items in the cell in the top of the column. It was working for me. Formula someone else can make.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Power Query, it just takes a few seconds...

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

This you can copy and paste it where you want.
Then you can delete the Query if you don't need it anymore, or you can update it when new values are added to your original table.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Mac doesn't support this use of power query at the moment very annoyingly though so unfortunately I am unable to do this. Hopefully this is helpful for others

Comment: @KatieJones Perhaps you can switch to the ***Current Channel Preview*** version (16.64), which should have power query available.

Answer (score 0):

Here a formula based solution.
This is for max. 3 items in a cell. You can make more formulas understanding the example in case you have more than 3 items in a cell.

B4=

```
=LEFT(A4;MIN(SEARCH({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A4&"0123456789";3))-1)
```

C4=

```
=MID(A4;
MIN(SEARCH({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A4&"0123456789";3));
MIN(SEARCH({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A4&"0123456789";MIN(SEARCH({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A4&"0123456789";3))+3))-MIN(SEARCH({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A4&"0123456789";3)))
```

C4=

```
=MID(A4;
MIN(SEARCH({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A4&"0123456789";3));
MIN(SEARCH({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A4&"0123456789";MIN(SEARCH({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A4&"0123456789";3))+3))-MIN(SEARCH({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A4&"0123456789";3)))
```

Formula in C9:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C4;" ";"");"%";"% ")
```

You can wrap it around the above formulas. I didn't do it, because otherwise it looks to complicated for you.

[image]